# Weird JQuery-AJAX append/text/html

Tags: jquery

I have a JQ-AJAX function that retrieves some results, and then on success it should make a list and add it to an element. I create an UL based on the results - here is the success function:

```
success: function (info) {
        var shipActionsUL = '<ul class="shipActionsList>';

        $(info).find('string').each(function (index) {
            var action = $(this).text();
            shipActionsUL += '<li id="'+action+'">'+action+'</li>';

        });

        shipActionsUL += '</ul>';
        $('#hello').text(shipActionsUL);

    }
```

Now, when the text of #hello changes, the result is:

```
<ul class="shipActionsList>
    <li id="aaMove">aaMove</li>
    <li id="aaAttack">aaAttack</li>
</ul>
```

Which is what I want the UL to look like in the DOM. However this is the literal text. When I try to actually make the list with $('#hello').html(shipActionsUL); I get a weirdly formated UL - its first List Item missing its bullet, and it looks like this when I inspect the list:

```
<ul class="shipActionsList>
    <li id=" aamove">aaMove</li>
    <li id="aaAttack">aaAttack</li>
</ul>
```

Notice the id of aamove - lower case and the extra space before it. Regardless of the List items in the list, it's always the first element that is messed up.

Also, if I would remove the ID from the list items having only

```
   shipActionsUL += '<li>'+action+'</li>';
```

A list would not appear in the #hello at all on $('#hello').html(shipActionsUL);

The XML response - info from success - would be in this format (now only aaAttack would be messed up):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ShipActions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <shipID>162</shipID>
 <Actions>
    <string>aaAttack</string>
    <string>aaMove</string>
    <string>aaSttack</string>
 </Actions>
 </ShipActions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you are missing a closing quote on the UL tag:

```
var shipActionsUL = '<ul class="shipActionsList">'; //Previously missing closing double quote.
```

Also, if you don't want the ID to contain the extra space, you can trim the `action`:

```
var action = $(this).text().trim();
```

Comment: Wow... that's it! I kept thinking the problem was the parsing... what a stupid thingy that takes up too much time. Thanks!

Comment: It happens! :) And yeah, as an FYI, a valid HTML ID should begin with a letter and must not contain spaces, so it's a good idea to trim it.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange that there's no space before the text node of the first list item. What if you do:

```
var action = $.trim($(this).text());
```